# InvalidOperationException when adding Migration. Can't resolve service for type IHttpContextAccessor

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am getting the following error when I am trying to add a migration.

Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Http.IHttpContextAccessor' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNet.ViewFeatures.TempDataDictionary'

I did a quick test and both of these types are available through Dependency Injection.

EF7 ASP.Net 5 RC1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this error occurred because my DbContext class didn't have an empty constructor. My constructor took in a type that DI needed to provide an IHttpContextAccessor to. When running in a browser, everything works fine, but when running ef commands from the console, DI was able to provide this type.